# ipad device not mirroring on testcomplete

Tags: ios, ipad, functional-testing, testcomplete

I am trying to automate ipad application test with test framework Test complete. Upon trying to capture a test case, testcomplete recognizes the device but mirroring fails? anyone has experience with iOS testing with testcomplete?

Comment: does this has to do with device jail brake anything?

Comment: Did you [instrument](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/75619/) your tested app? Also, you'll probably have better luck asking [SmartBear support](https://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete) or posting on [TestComplete forum](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Mobile-Application-Testing/bd-p/Mobile_Application_Testing) than here.

Comment: I already asked smartbear support but still no reply from their side

Answer (score 0):

although I am a bit late, I thought sharing my answer might be a good idea.
TestComplete cannot mirror everything you do on iOS (like on Android), it can only mirror what you do in your instrumented app. This is why it displays a message "No TestedApp running". Just run any TestedApp on your device using the "Run app" button in the toolbar of the Mobile Screen Window and you should be done.